# No internet access and taskbar panel icon in Ubuntu 20.04 when I use kernel 4.4.230

Tags: kernel, internet

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04, and the kernel version is `5.4.0-40-generic`; this is the original desktop image I download from canonical, and it works fine in wired and wireless internet. But I need to install Linux kernel `4.4.230` required by the project. In the older kernel, there is no internet access at all even for tethering. I have made a few attempts to figure it out, but I am still very confused about the situation.

Ping is not working:

```
~$ ping 8.8.8.8
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
```

And I checked network by this:

```
~$ lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:52:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ce300000-ce303fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       version: 10
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ce400000-ce41ffff
```

Comment: The older kernel doesn't contain the required drivers (kernel modules) that support the newer hardware that you have.

Comment: @heynnema I think that is the answer to the question as written, although perhaps Tom is asking how to get internet working with this setup, which could be tricky...

Comment: @Zanna Yes, it may take something like backported drivers, if they exist for this newer hardware. I won't take it on. Maybe chili55 will jump on the opportunity :-)

Comment: Accually I installed ubuntu16.04 before with kernel `4.15`,wired internet is working. And I installed firware for **AX200** and kernel `5.1`, wireless internet works too. Then I upgrade to ubuntu18.04, all the internet access seems to have problems. Does it mean I have to stick to Ubuntu16.04, and accept the fact that only wired connection is available? But I found it hard to install Nvidia drive in Ubuntu16.04, which confuses me a lot.